# find variable in xml

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have several xml's that I need to compare. Problem is, there are two elements in that needs to be removed because they are always different.

```
<section name="Cache">
        <section name="Registry">
            <key name="Expiration" description="Value range: 0 - &amp;infin; Seconds" summary="Defines the registry entry cache expiration time" range="0-" type="integer" defaultvalue="300" modifiedby="user_x" modificationtime="2020-11-17T12:08:36.1900000+00:00" readonly="False" ismultivalue="False">300</key>
        </section>
        <section name="UserSession">
            <key name="Expiration" description="Value range: 0 - &amp;infin; Seconds" summary="Defines the session cache expiration time" range="0-" type="integer" defaultvalue="30" modifiedby="user_x" modificationtime="2020-11-17T12:08:36.1900000+00:00" readonly="False" ismultivalue="False">30</key>
        </section>
    </section>
```

`modifiedby` is a constant in the xml, so I can remove that with:

```
tree = ET.parse(xml1)
root = tree.getroot()

xmlstr = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml')
xmlstr = xmlstr.replace(b'user_x', b'')
```

But how can I remove the `modificationtime` from the xml knowing this is a variable that cannot be predicted? This `modificationtime` returns in every element of the XML

Comment: Do you wanna remove the value of that attribute only or remove the attribute altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to do all replacements working with `ElementTree` before convert it back to string, otherwise there's no reason to parse *XML* at all:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(xml1)
root = tree.getroot()
# here we go
for key in root.findall('.//key'):
    key.attrib['modifiedby'] = ''
    key.attrib['modificationtime'] = ''
# and finally convert to bytestring
xmlstr = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml') # add .decode() to get string
```

`.//key` here is *XPath expression*, you can read more about that in latest [XML Path Language Standart](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-31-20170321/#abbrev). It'll help you to adapt code to work with XML document with different structure.